# How to bypass authentication middleware when not needed in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following authentication handler:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthenticationHandler (
        IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var data = await GetDataFromDatabase(); //heavy load
        if(data.IsAuth)
        {
          var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
          var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
          var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

          return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
       }
       return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Failed("Not authenticated"));
    }
}
```

I register it like this in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
      options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CustomAuthenticationSchemeOptions.SchemeName;
      options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CustomAuthenticationSchemeOptions.SchemeName;
    })
    .AddScheme<CustomAuthenticationSchemeOptions, CustomAuthenticationHandler>(CustomAuthenticationSchemeOptions.SchemeName, null);
```

Then I use it like this in `Configure`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I have several `Controllers` with several `Actions`. Some of those actions should be accessed only after authentication.

I thought that if I use the `[Authorize]` attribute, I make sure that only authenticated users can access it, so my middleware will be called with that request and the authentication protocol is executed (I guess it would be a very elegant and efficient solution).

```
public class RegisterController: ControllerBase
{
   public async Task<AsyncResult<int>>> Reg(string name)
   {
     //...
   }
}

[Authorize]
public class DataController: Controller
{
   public async Task<AsyncResult<Data>>> GetData(int dataId)
   {
     //...
   }
}
```

It seems that I was wrong, as *each middleware is [called each time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder) when a request arrives*.

So if I don't want to search the database after each `Action` request, I have to filter when the middleware is used.

I see some condition-based solution to use [`app.UseWhen`](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/conditional-middleware-based-on-request-in-asp.net-core) and test the request path and other cumbersome ways.

Is there a more elegant and efficient way? As I have many actions, I can't create path checking for every one of them.

Comment: Have you put the `Authorize` attribute at controller level or at action level?

Comment: It varies, some of them are at `Controller`, some of them are at `Action` level.

Comment: `app.UseWhen` + custom attribute like `NoAuthRequired` checking on httpcontext endpoint metadata can be used instead of routing checking, quite elegant solution in my opinion

Comment: like this 

`app.UseWhen(c => !c.EndpointHasAttribute<NoAuthRequiredAttribute>(), 
                          b => b.UseAuthentication()`

and extension EndpointHasAttribute

`context.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<T>() != null`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you add Authorization to your middleware pipeline this will be the default for all calls to your API. Therefore all calls will act as though they have the `[Authorize]` attribute applied.

This is normally desirable as it means by default your application is secure and you can't accidently forget an [Authorize] attribute. I'd recommend keeping it like this and simply add the `[AllowAnonymous]` tag to the controllers or controller actions you want to be public.

If you want to be explicit at all times you simply remove `app.UseAuthentication();` You will still be able to use `[Authorize]` which will trigger your middleware as you have added the service for use. But it will not automatically trigger for all calls.

**Additional:**

In order to use authorization without having to specify the scheme per call you can set your scheme as a default authorization policy.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        CustomAuthenticationSchemeOptions.SchemeName);

    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = 
        defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
});
```

To extend what others have said there are subtle differences between Authentication and Authrorization. Authentication says who a user is, Authorization say what they are allowed to do. All the above simply says is... provided I know who a user is (Is Authenticated) they are allowed to use my actions (Is Authorized). So your default authorization policy is effectively if a user is successfully authenticated.

Comment: We are almost there :) If I remove the `app.UseAuthentication();` and call the `GetData` method, my middleware isn't executed. If I add the scheme name explicitly (like `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "CustomAuthScheme")]`), it is called. Can I somehow force the pipeline to use my scheme as the default scheme?

Comment: I've added an additional section above. See if this helps.

Comment: [AllowAnonymous]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing authentication and authorization. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-2.2),

> Authentication is a process in which a user provides credentials that are then compared to those stored in an operating system, database, app or resource. If they match, users authenticate successfully, and can then perform actions that they're authorized for, during an authorization process. The authorization refers to the process that determines what a user is allowed to do.

What you have created is an authentication handler. Authentication runs regardless of whether there is an authorize attribute, as the purpose of authentication is not only authorization. It is also identification. You should setup authentication in a way that does not cause db load on every request, such as by issuing in a JSON Web Token or an Application Cookie at a selected endpoint such as `/account/login`. Once you have authentication setup in this manner, you can setup a custom **authorization handler** or authorization attribute that checks the claims through `HttpContext.User.Claims` to see whether the User is authorized to access the resource, (and even perform light db activity for this matter, such as looking up user roles.)

This guide outlines [how to setup authorization handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-owner-manager-and-administrator-authorization-handlers), but you can start by reading up on [authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2) first.

Comment: Useful insights but I think, authentication and authorization are linked together. Sometimes authentication IS authorization as in this case: if the user is authenticated, then the user is allowed to do anything that requires authorization as there are no roles here to separate authorization levels.

Comment: Understood. You are referring do the default level of authorisation which is simply being authenticated. Are you unable to memoize the authentication result to a token or cookie?

Comment: It's a special case but this kind of authentication should be achievable regardless.

Comment: In that case, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x It outlines how to set defaults. It's basically overriding the default authorisation policy to use the specified authentication scheme.

Comment: Yes, namely this section helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-multiple-authentication-schemes _As the default authorization policy is overridden, it's possible to use the [Authorize] attribute in controllers. The controller then accepts requests with JWT issued by the first or second issuer._